# Angularjs not navigating to specific page directly by url

Tags: angularjs

I am developing in angularjs 1.7

I am having Index page as masterpage and I am calling route1.html into that page.

When I click menu item from header for route1.html it works well. But If I access directly this link `http://localhost:56631/route1` it gives 404 error. This also happens on back navigation. Is there anything I am missing

app.js

```
(function () {

    var myapp = angular.module('myApp', ["ui.router"]);

    myapp.config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/route1")

        $stateProvider
          .state('route1', {
              url: "/route1",
              templateUrl: "SOC/Views/route1.html",
              controller: "route1ctrl"
          })
          .state('route2', {
              url: "/route2",
              templateUrl: "SOC/Views/route2.html",
              controller: "route2ctrl"
          })
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });

    });


})();
```

Menu item in header page

```
<li><a ui-sref="route1">Route 1</a></li>
```

Comment: if you just want to redirect to `route1` state then you can use `$state.go("route1")`

Comment: @Shaheryar.Akram where do i need to add that

Comment: assuming you want to redirect to `route1` state from a controller, you can write this in a controller.

Comment: but the problem is i am using same controller for multiple pages. So is there a way to check if its only route1 then do `$state.go("route1")`

Comment: I don't entirely understand your problem but you can append `functions` on your buttons or checks whatever your requirement is, in this way `ng-click="functionName()"` and in the js write this function which does that `$state.go`